# Getting last change in component based SVN project

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

With my limited knowledge

In one of my projects, I have component-based structure.

```
ParentFolder ->ComponentFolderOne->branches->test24->.svn
             ->ComponentFolderTwo->branches->test24->.svn
             ->ComponentFolderThree->branches->test24->.svn
             ->ComponentFolderFour->branches->test24->.svn
             ..............................................
             ->ComponentFolderHundred->branches->test24->.svn
```

Now a whole lot of people are working on the same project on different components.

In order to find who did the last few changes, it is pretty difficult.
I have to go into each of the components and check svn show log to know the history.

**What I would like to get is:**
Who made the last set of changes. I would like to get this status for a particular branch only.

Is this a general problem? My thinking is even if I use **git** for such a project will face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small program which will:

- [get the list of branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104662/get-all-branch-names-in-svn)
- iterate them
- check the last change and its owner
- compare the last change times to find the maximum

You could also use a tool which could help you, like [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

However, it is recommendable to use git instead of SVN